# Disable SortableJS's selecting and programmaticaly select elements

Tags: javascript, sortablejs

I'm having troubles with SortableJS's selecting system (mainly the MultiDrag plugin). I want to be able to programmaticaly select and deselect the elements that are to be dragged, but also want to disable the built-in click-selecting. In other words, I want to disable the click-to-select functionality of SortableJS AND MultiDrag and only select the items via the provided select and deselect functions. I tried fiddling with the code myself but it's a bit too convoluted for my understanding and I couldn't find where the actual selecting is happening and how the MultiDrag plugin is keeping track of the selected items. Does anyone have experience with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the deselection on the item clicked.
Eg

```
$(element).on('pointerup mouseup touchend', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

See https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable/issues/1612#issuecomment-533777362